# Oracle11GR2 Automating Database Startup and Shutdown on Linux

Tags: linux, centos

I have some problems with the automatic Database Startup and Shutdown in CentOS 6.8.

I've followed this [guide](https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/automating-database-startup-and-shutdown-on-linux#oracle-11gr2-update), I've created "/etc/init.d/dbora" the script changing the 
ORA_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/9.2.0 in ORA_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1

and also I'have changed: 
OBMS(the name of the database):/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:N in Y.

However, when I reboot the OS, I take this message

```
Message 1070 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNSTNS-12545: Message 12545 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
 TNS-12560: Message 12560 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
  TNS-00515: Message 515 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
   Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory
Processing Database instance "OBMS": log file /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/startup.log
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, follow this [guide](http://www.oracledistilled.com/oracle-database/administration/automating-database-startupshutdown-on-oracle-enterprise-linux/)
I've set the `ORACLE_HOME_LISTNER = $ORACLE_HOME` in the script dbstart